# How to use multiple form fields for array values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with an attribute that is an array. Here is an example:

```
class BlogPost
  def tags
    ["example 1", "example 2"]
  end
end
```

I want to be able to edit that array in my form using multiple fields but still keep it as an array. I know that my controller needs to accept an array:

```
def permitted_params
  params.require(:blog_post).permit(tags: [])
end
```

However, I'm not sure how to render the form fields correctly. This results in the wrong field names:

```
<%= form_with model: @blog_post do |form| %>
  <% @blog_post.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= form.text_field "tags[]", value: tag %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails form field helpers support a `multiple: true` option for specifying the correct field name:

```
<%= form_with model: @blog_post do |form| %>
  <% @blog_post.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= form.text_field :tags, multiple: true, value: tag %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

...results in fields that look like:

```
<input type="text" name="blog_post[tags][]" value="example 1">
<input type="text" name="blog_post[tags][]" value="example 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `tag.object` please

```
<% @todo_array.each do |tag| %>
  <%= form.text_field "tags[]", value: tag.object %>
<% end %>
```